# draw latitude/longitude lines in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I can't figure out how to draw latitude/longitude lines in R on a map. There must be a way -- this is what I'm trying:

```
library("maps")
library("mapproj")
map("world")
map.axes()
map.grid(c(-180,180,-90,90),col=2,nx=5,ny=5,label=TRUE,lty=2)
```

However, no matter how I adjust the `nx` and `ny` values, I can never get the exact latitude and longitude lines that I want. I am aiming to get a 6x4 grid that divides my map on the longitude lines -180, -120, -60,0,60,120,180 and on the latitude lines 90,45,0,-45,-90.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is `pretty=FALSE` :

```
library("maps")
library("mapproj")
map("world")
map.axes()
map.grid(c(-180,180,-90,90),col=2,nx=7,ny=5, pretty=FALSE, label=TRUE,lty=2)
```